# Solution for viewing wireless IP cameras in real time on a monitor

Tags: monitors, camera, home-security, ip-camera, dvr

I installed some wireless IP cameras in my parents' house. They work great. The only problem, especially for them who are over 65 years old, is how to watch them quickly and easily.

Currently, they need to open a slow mobile app or a computer, which may or may not be on at the time, whenever they hear a suspicious sound or someone at the door. By the time they finally manage to do it, it's almost always too late.

Basically, what they need is some way to keep the camera images running all day on a monitor. Something that is very common for wired cameras.

Is there any equipment or solution that allows this? Something like a DVR but for wireless IP cameras.

I thought about buying a cheap laptop that would stay on 24/7 for this purpose, but it's hard to accept that there isn't a dedicated solution better than that. Can someone help me please?

Comment: There are DVRs that connect to wireless IP cameras. Did you already search for that and find nothing? What model(s) of IP cameras are they?

Comment: @Romen For some reason google wasn't able to return any significant result. Now that you reinforced the idea that there are DVRs for wireless cameras, I was able to find that they're called "Wireless Multi-channel NVRs". Thanks!
They're using generic "Icsee" external cameras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find out, with Romen's help, that the hardware I'm looking for is called a **Wireless Multi-channel NVR**. Not exactly a DVR.

Comment: Glad you figured this out! When you get a chance (and once it'll let you) can you mark this question as answered?